# Is it possible to derive a Traversable instance via another type constructor?

Tags: haskell, deriving, derivingvia

Suppose we have some class `Foo` such that an instance of `Foo f` gives us everything necessary to implement `Functor f`, `Foldable f` and `Traversable f`. To avoid overlapping instances, can witness this relationship between `Foo` and `Functor, Foldable, Traversable` under a newtype wrapper:

```hs
type Foo :: (Type -> Type) -> Constraint
class Foo f
  where
  {- ... -}

type FoonessOf :: (Type -> Type) -> Type -> Type
newtype FoonessOf f a = FoonessOf (f a)

instance Foo f => Functor (FoonessOf f)
  where
  fmap = _

instance Foo f => Foldable (FoonessOf f)
  where
  foldMap = _

instance Foo f => Traversable (FoonessOf f)
  where
  traverse = _
```

Now suppose we have some type constructor:

```hs
data Bar a = Bar {- ... -}
```

such that there is an:

```hs
instance Foo Bar
  where
  {- ... -}
```

We'd like to equip `Bar` with the instances implied by its "`Foo`-ness". Since `Bar a` is `Coercible` to `FoonessOf Bar a`, we'd expect to be able to derive the instances `via` the `FoonessOf Bar`:

```hs
deriving via (FoonessOf Bar) instance Functor Bar
deriving via (FoonessOf Bar) instance Foldable Bar
```

And this works handily for typeclasses such as `Functor` and `Foldable`

Unfortunately when we try to do the same thing with `Traversable`, things go awry:

```hs
[typecheck -Wdeferred-type-errors] [E] • Couldn't match representation of type ‘f1 (Foo Bar a1)’
                           with that of ‘f1 (Bar a1)’
    arising from a use of ‘ghc-prim-0.6.1:GHC.Prim.coerce’
  NB: We cannot know what roles the parameters to ‘f1’ have;
    we must assume that the role is nominal
• In the expression:
      ghc-prim-0.6.1:GHC.Prim.coerce
        @(Foo Bar (f a) -> f (Foo Bar a)) @(Bar (f a) -> f (Bar a))
        (sequenceA @(Foo Bar)) ::
        forall (f :: TYPE ghc-prim-0.6.1:GHC.Types.LiftedRep
                     -> TYPE ghc-prim-0.6.1:GHC.Types.LiftedRep)
               (a :: TYPE ghc-prim-0.6.1:GHC.Types.LiftedRep).
        Applicative f => Bar (f a) -> f (Bar a)
  In an equation for ‘sequenceA’:
      sequenceA
        = ghc-prim-0.6.1:GHC.Prim.coerce
            @(Foo Bar (f a) -> f (Foo Bar a)) @(Bar (f a) -> f (Bar a))
            (sequenceA @(Foo Bar)) ::
            forall (f :: TYPE ghc-prim-0.6.1:GHC.Types.LiftedRep
                         -> TYPE ghc-prim-0.6.1:GHC.Types.LiftedRep)
                   (a :: TYPE ghc-prim-0.6.1:GHC.Types.LiftedRep).
            Applicative f => Bar (f a) -> f (Bar a)
  When typechecking the code for ‘sequenceA’
    in a derived instance for ‘Traversable Bar’:
    To see the code I am typechecking, use -ddump-deriv
  In the instance declaration for ‘Traversable Bar’
——————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————
...
```

So the questions I have are:

1. Is it possible to come up with some other scheme for deriving-via the instance `Traversable Bar`?
2. Is it possible to come up with some modification of the `Traversable` class that can be derived via a newtype?

Comment: I've been wishing that the `Traversable` method were `fmapTraverse :: Applicative f => (t b -> r) -> (a -> f b) -> t a -> f r`. That would take care of the type role issue, and also remove the extra `fmap`s from lots of traversals. There could additionally be `coerceTraverse :: (Applicative f, Coercible (t b) r) => (a -> f b) -> t a -> f r` for further performance magic.

Answer (score 4):

I suspect the answer to 1. is: no, the situation cannot be salvaged, and it is impossible to obtain an instance of `Traversable` using `DerivingVia`.

---

As far as 2. goes, it's useful to try and reproduce the problem in a simpler context. Consider the following:

```hs
-- Remember to turn on ScopedTypeVariables!

data A = A
newtype B = B A

a :: forall f. f A -> f A
a = id

b :: forall f. f B -> f B
b = coerce $ a @f
```

It seems like this should work, but alas:

```hs
[typecheck -Wdeferred-type-errors] [E] • Couldn't match representation of type ‘f A’ with that of ‘f B’
    arising from a use of ‘coerce’
  NB: We cannot know what roles the parameters to ‘f’ have;
    we must assume that the role is nominal
• In the expression: coerce $ a @f
  In an equation for ‘b’: b = coerce $ a @f
• Relevant bindings include
    b :: f B -> f B
```

---

The problem has to do with the "roles" of type constructors' parameters, and the way role inference works. For our purposes, roles come in two varieties: "representational" and "non-representational". Also for our purposes, the difference between the two can be approximated to the following: a type constructor `F :: Type -> Type` has a parameter of a "representational" role if there is an instance of `Representational F`, where:

```
type Representational :: (Type -> Type) -> Constraint
type Representational f = forall x y. Coercible x y => Coercible (f x) (f y)
```

Otherwise, the parameter of `F` is non-representational.

---

The typechecker lets you annotate the roles of type parameters in various places (although strangely enough, not in the kind). Sadly, there is no way to annotate the roles of a higher kinded type variable. What we can do however is just ask for `Representational f` directly:

```
b' :: forall f. Representational f => f B -> f B
b' = coerce $ a @f
```

which now typechecks. This suggests a possible way to tweak the `Traversable` typeclass to make it derivable via coercions.

---

Now let's look at the type of the `Traversable` operation `sequenceA`:

```hs
class Traversable t
  where
  sequenceA :: forall f. Applicative f => forall a. t (f a) -> f (t a)
  {- ... -}
```

NB: There's that pesky `forall f` again, meaning `f` is taken to have a type parameter of a nominal role.

What `DerivingVia` is going to do is attempt to `coerce` between:

```hs
sequenceA @T1 :: forall f. Applicative f => forall a. T1 (f a) -> f (T2 a)
```

and:

```hs
sequenceA @T2 :: forall f. Applicative f => forall a. T2 (f a) -> f (T2 a)
```

Despite `T1` (`FoonessOf Bar`) and `T2` (`Bar`) being "parametrically" coercible, this coercion will fail, because the coercion of the entire operation will decompose eventually to the coercion the typechecker complained about:

```hs
Couldn't match representation of type
‘f1 (Foo Bar a1)’
with that of
‘f1 (Bar a1)’
```

This doesn't work because of `f`'s parameter being considered to have a nominal role, as we discussed.

As with our simplified example above, the fix is straightforward: just ask for `Representational f`:

```hs
type Traversable' :: (Type -> Type) -> Constraint
class Traversable' t
  where
  traverse :: (Representational f, Applicative f) => (a -> f b) -> t (f a) -> f (t b)
```

And now at last we can derive an instance of `Traversable'` via the `FoonessOf Bar`:

```hs
instance Foo f => Traversable' (FoonessOf f)
  where
  traverse = _

deriving via (FoonessOf Bar) instance Traversable' Bar
```

Comment: `representational` lies *between* `phantom` and `nominal`. Something whose type parameter has a phantom role would certainly be an instance of your `Representational`.

Comment: @dfeuer oh, I see. good to know, i've edited the answer